# How to create multiple shopping cart/basket in NOPCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

Currently, we are developing new ecommerce web site using nopcommerce. The one of requirement is that customer should be able to create multiple shopping basket. In current nopcommerce system can only handle single shopping basket. customer can't create or save multiple shopping basket.

I haven't found much information online as well.

Has anyone created this kind of functionally? are there any plug-in already exist?

please share some idea how to archive functionally.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement might be having different shopping cart for separate store. You can check for

```
 int storeId=  //Get this from url or urlreferrer
 var cart = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.ShoppingCartItems.Where(sc => 
    sc.ProductVariant.Product.StoreId.Equals(storeId)).ToList();
```